# What is the Life Cycle of an iPhone application?

Tags: ios, lifecycle

Can anyone explain what is the life cycle process of iPhone? i.e from the start to end of the application life cycle.

Comment: I had found an article which has gud explanation abt the app life cycle, please refer to the below doc. I hope it will be helpful others.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/ApplicationLifeCycle.aspx

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121681/Application-s-Life-Cycle-in-iOS4

Answer (score 125):

See also [This post on Cocoanetics](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/) that present a very useful flowchart explaining the different calls to the AppDelegate methods during the app life cycle:

[image: UIApplication Delegate messaging flowchart]

Comment: Is this still valid for ios5?

Comment: @KronoS - Yes, the only time this changed significantly was the introduction of multitasking in iOS 4.0. It's still viable as of iOS 5.0 (and should continue to be so for iOS 6.0).

Comment: Apple/iOS does not send the `applicationWillTerminate` message. About all you will get is a `SIGTRM` when the operating system wants you out of memory. The docs have been broken for years.

Comment: iOS does send the `applicationWillTerminale` message, but only in the cases explained in the diagram, namely if you were compiling with SDK<4 (which can't be the case nowadays) or if you set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES` in your app's `Info.plist`. So the diagram is still right ;)

Answer (score 115):

here is diagram image for **understand Life Cycle (iPhone / Android)**

[image]

---

**Edit:** Here is the more detailed information from [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html).

> Part 1:

[image]

> Part 2:

[image]

[Reference](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2012/03/developer-view-ios-view-controller.html)

Also this one is for **View Controller Life Cycle methods**

[image]

Comment: is there a diagram like this but using the applicationDid|Will methods?

Comment: @Keale please check [this official](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) page have all the information with diagrams.

Comment: The Apple reference links are broken. Here are updated ones: [The App Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW1)
and [The Launch Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW3)

Answer (score 20):

There's another simpler one in ios developer's cookbook

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to something more detail ,you can read the official document delivered by apple 
It has been updated with iOS6.0
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html

Comment: The App Life Cycle Updated with iOS 9 :  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html