# Alternative to UIApplicationMain for cross platform application.

Tags: android, ios, macos, window, cross-platform

I am creating a class for creating window for multiple platforms including `Windows, Mac, Linux, iOS and Android`. I want my class to work the following way

```
    MyWindow window( "My Window", 480, 320 );
    while( window.IsRunning() )
    {
        // do something
    }
```

However, on **iOS**, we are needed to call `UIApplicationMain` after main is called which takes care of all the internal stuff and the main loop. I was wondering if there was any way to bypass `UIApplicationMain` so that I could get control of the main loop on iOS? A working code example would be of great help.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't, really. It needs to be called. If you need this, you probably have a design problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @H2CO3 told, You cant.

There are many limitations , Eg: iOS mobile app can have only one window, but the Mac OS can have multiple window, how will you handle that?

Also see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121681/Application-s-Life-Cycle-in-iOS4) and [App Life Cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519847/what-is-the-life-cycle-of-an-iphone-application) and [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iPhoneAppProgrammingGuide.pdf)

But you can follow some time saving tricks.

You can design your code in parts

1. Code that handle data
2. Code that handle the UI update

   Design your UI according to the native app SDK, then update UI according to the call backs.

   You can use different tools for converting you code
   like [Google's Java To Obj C](http://code.google.com/p/j2objc/) and [ObjC to java](http://code.google.com/p/objc2j/)

Only some part of code can be reused, but most of the part you have rewrite for different platforms.

You can also try to use some [cross platforms](http://mobiledevices.about.com/od/mobileappbasics/tp/Top-5-Tools-Multi-Platform-Mobile-App-Development.htm).