# Alarms and phone call with AppleTV

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-tv

I have a big problem, and I cannot find any documentation or solution.
I'm rendering images in the iPhone (like a film), and I have to mirror it to TV, but when alarm comes front the rendering stops while my app is behind the alarm dialog. Can I somehow render my images in the background? or have somebody a link for the exact documentation I'm searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answere:
YES you can render images / videos in the backgound.

For some help read:
[What is the Life Cycle of an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519847/what-is-the-life-cycle-of-an-iphone-application)

**EDIT:**
There is an image of the OS's lifecycle:
[image]

From this image you can see the main functions, the OS calls. If you need to render in backround you should stop the rendering at the ApplicationDidEnterInBackgound method.
The OS does not garantee the function's call, but if you stop every task on applicationWillResignActive, you cannot render on background.

Comment: Can you summarize the info a the link? Links break over time, making answers like this one useless.