# How to reload website page via swift when you click on UItabButton for iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am working on a swift iPhone application that loads a website page on viewDidLoad() function but I am stumped and have not been able to figure this next part out.

Basically what I am trying to do:

The dashboard controller (tab format) connects to three different pages which the first time you click on the tab it loads the page correctly via the viewDidLoad()

However when I go to a different tab then click back I need it to reload except it doesn't run the viewDidLoad() function again to load it.

Is there a function I can access or call? I have looked through app documents but I have failed to find it.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: use viewDidAppear?

Comment: Here is some basic of iOS dev life cycle for your better understanding. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519847/what-is-the-life-cycle-of-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below view life cycle delegate method:

As per my understanding reloading a Webpage is not a UI update, So if you will use `viewWillAppear` so it will call before `viewDidAppear` which helps you to request faster.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated : Bool)
{
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for `viewDidAppear`, which likes like the following in Swift 3 ...

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    super.viewDidAppear(animated) //call superclass's implementation first

    //do stuff here ie. reload() 
}
```